# has_one / belongs_to approach

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple relationship:

```
Student 
has_one :locker, inverse_of: :student, validate: true, dependent: :nullify
accepts_nested_attributes_for :locker

Locker  
belongs_to :student, inverse_of: :locker, touch: true
```

I have a form with this:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :locker do |l| %>
  <%= l.input :id, as: :select,
      collection: @lockers_collection,
      label: false,
      value_method: :id,
      label_method: :number,
      include_blank: true,
      input_html: { class: "admin-select2" },
      selected: "#{@student.locker ? @student.locker.id : ""}",
      wrapper: 'admin_vertical_select' -%>
<% end -%>
```

When i am creating new Student i can assign a locker (or not), and everything is simple and works as expected. Well, I had to add this hackery to Student model, otherwise Rails was complaining about not finding a record (solution found here on SO):

```
def locker_attributes=(attributes)
  if attributes['id'].present?
    self.locker = Locker.find(attributes['id'])
  end
  super
end
```

Anyway, what I have major problems with are the edit/update actions.
First I need to check if Student currently has a locker or not to build a new one or existing:

```
if @student.locker
  @student.build_locker(id: @student.locker.id)
else
  @student.build_locker
end
```

Now the real problem i am trying to find solution to.
There are basically few scenarios that can happen:

- Student didn't have locker and will not have locker.
- Student has a locker but i want to clear it

  In this two scenarios Student is not updated, because (I suspect) Locker is empty. How to deal with this?

Then there is also possibility of changing Locker from one to another.
In this case, i somehow thought Rails will be smart enough to update the "old" Locker. I can see the student_id id on old locker is nil, but how does Rails do that? The problem is I have a paper_trail on Locker and i need the old one to be versioned when it becomes empty.

How do I deal with empty scenarios? This is my biggest problem.
Am I doing it right or is there a better way to do it?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

If you add the `inverse_of` to your associations in your models like:

- Student: `has_one :locker, inverse_of: :student`
- Locker:  `belongs_to :student, inverse_of: :locker`

You would be able to only use:

```
@student.build_locker unless @student.locker
```

And you wouldn't need the `def locker_attributes=(attributes)` method.

To nullify the locker you could add the following to an action in some controller, like this:

```
@student.locker = nil
@student.save
```

Comment: Hey Mario. I actually have inverse_of defined, forgot to mention it. I will update my question. Anyway, it doesn't work without that method.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: I can't just nullify and save a locker. What if some other attributes on Student are changed? Like address etc...

Comment: I meant more having the nullification in one action. If you don't want that then you would need to have a checkbox in your view to indicate a "Remove", and use that checkbox as a flag on the controller side, so you still do all the usual update with the params, but you nullify if that flag is present.